# how to perform a multi-task deep neural network training

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was trying to build a multi-task deep neural network with a profile function for complexity tuning. My goal is to train the network with this function and compute three different losses with their corresponding training accuracies based on the percentage of channel profiles for three different ranges, (0% - 20%), (20% - 40%) and (40% - 100%) as shown in my code below. Please is what I'm doing correct or is there a suggestion of how best I can do it?

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)

# Network Parameters
n_1 = 100               # 1st layer number of neurons
n_2 = 100               # 2nd layer number of neurons
n_input = 784           #MNIST data input (img shape: 28*28)
n_classes = 10          # MNIST total classes (0-9 digits)
learning_rate = 0.0008
training_epochs = 20
batch_size = 30
display_step = 1


np.random.seed(1)
# tf Graph input
tf.reset_default_graph()
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_input])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_classes])

# Store layers weight & bias
def initialize_param(n_input, n_1, n_2, n_class):
    tf.set_random_seed(1)
    W1 = tf.get_variable("W1", shape = [n_input, n_1], 
        initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(seed = 1))
    b1 = tf.get_variable("b1", shape = [n_1], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer())
    W2 = tf.get_variable("W2", shape = [n_1, n_2], initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(seed = 1))
    b2 = tf.get_variable("b2", shape = [n_2], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer())
    W3 = tf.get_variable("W3", shape = [n_2, n_class], initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(seed = 1))
    b3 = tf.get_variable("b3", shape = [n_class], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer())

    parameters = {"W1": W1,"b1": b1,"W2": W2,"b2": b2,"W3": W3,"b3": b3}
    return parameters
parameters = initialize_param(784, 100, 100, 10)

def linear_func(n):
    return[np.float32(1.0 - 1.0 * i/n) for i in range(1, n + 1)]
L = linear_func(100)

def linear_profile(lp, n_1):
    p_L = tf.constant(L, shape = [1, 100])
    L_11 = tf.constant(1.0, shape = [1, int(np.round((lp) * n_1))])
    L_12 = tf.zeros(shape = [1, int(np.round((1 - lp) * n_1))])
    L1 = tf.concat((L_11, L_12), axis = 1)
    p_L1 = tf.multiply(L1, p_L)
    return p_L1

# Creating Multiple Profile
pc1 = np.linspace(0, 0.2, 100)
pc2 = np.linspace(0.2, 0.4, 100)
pc3 = np.linspace(0.4, 1.0, 100)
prof = {"p1": pc1, "p2": pc2, "p3":pc3}

profile_1 = []
profile_2 = []
profile_3 = []

for i, v in enumerate(prof):   
    if i == 0:
        pc1 = prof[v]
        for j in pc1:
            p_L1 = linear_profile(j, 100)
            profile = tf.stack(p_L1, axis = 0) 
            profile_1.append(profile)
        profile1 = tf.convert_to_tensor(profile_1, dtype=tf.float32) 

    elif i == 1:
        pc2 = prof[v]
        for j in pc2:
            p_L1 = linear_profile(j, 100)
            profile = tf.stack(p_L1, axis = 0) 
            profile_2.append(profile)
        profile2 = tf.convert_to_tensor(profile_2, dtype=tf.float32)

    elif i == 2:
        pc3 = prof[v]
        for j in pc3:
            p_L1 = linear_profile(j, 100)
            profile = tf.stack(p_L1, axis = 0) 
            profile_3.append(profile)
        profile3 = tf.convert_to_tensor(profile_3, dtype=tf.float32)

def mlp_1(x, profile_type):
    for j in range(len(pc1)):
        Z_ML11 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, parameters['W1']), parameters['b1'])  
        A_ML11 = tf.nn.relu(Z_ML11)
        P_ML11 = tf.multiply(profile_type[j], A_ML11)
        Z_ML12 = tf.add(tf.matmul(P_ML11, parameters['W2']), parameters['b2'])  
        A_ML12 = tf.nn.relu(Z_ML12)
        P_ML12 = tf.multiply(profile_type[j], A_ML12)
        out_layer = tf.add(tf.matmul(P_ML12, parameters['W3']), parameters['b3'])
        return out_layer

logits_1 = mlp_1(X, profile1)
logits_2 = mlp_1(X, profile2)
logits_3 = mlp_1(X, profile3)

# Define loss and optimizer
loss_op_1 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = logits_1, labels = Y))
loss_op_2 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = logits_2, labels = Y))
loss_op_3 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = logits_3, labels = Y))
optimizer_1 = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate, momentum = 0.98).minimize(loss_op_1)
optimizer_2 = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate, momentum = 0.98).minimize(loss_op_2)
optimizer_3 = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate, momentum = 0.98).minimize(loss_op_3)

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    # Training Loop
    cost_1 = []
    cost_2 = []
    cost_3 = []
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        avg_cost1 = 0.
        avg_cost2 = 0.
        avg_cost3 = 0.
        total_batch = int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)

        # Loop over all batches
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)

            # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
            _, c_1 = sess.run([loss_op_1, optimizer_1], feed_dict = {X: batch_x, Y: batch_y})
            _, c_2 = sess.run([loss_op_2, optimizer_2], feed_dict = {X: batch_x, Y: batch_y})
            _, c_3 = sess.run([loss_op_3, optimizer_3], feed_dict = {X: batch_x, Y: batch_y})

            # Compute average losses
            avg_cost1 += c_1 / total_batch
            avg_cost2 += c_2 / total_batch
            avg_cost3 += c_3 / total_batch
            cost_1.append(avg_cost1)
            cost_2.append(avg_cost2)
            cost_3.append(avg_cost3)

            logits_list = [logits_1, logits_2, logits_3]
            train_accuracy = []
            for r in logits_list:
                if i % 5000 == 0:
                    pred = tf.nn.softmax(logits_list[r])  # Apply softmax to logits
                    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(Y, 1))
                    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
                    trian_accuracy_1 = accuracy.eval({X: mnist.train.images, Y: mnist.train.labels})
                    train.append(trian_accuracy_1)

        # Display logs per epoch step
        avg_cost = [avg_cost1, avg_cost1, avg_cost1]
        for l in avg_cost:
            if epoch % display_step == 0:
                print("Epoch:", '%03d' % (epoch + 1), "cost = {:.9f}".format(avg_cost[l]))
    sess.close()
```

When the code is run, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-411b2efd4af7> in <module>()
    134 
    135             # Compute average losses
--> 136             avg_cost1 += c_1 / total_batch
    137             avg_cost2 += c_2 / total_batch
    138             avg_cost3 += c_3 / total_batch

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

.

Comment: can you provide the full error trace back please..

Comment: I was able to identify a mistake in computing the third loss. Instead of logits_3, I wrote logiits_3. However, whenever, the code is run, I get the following error: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-411b2efd4af7> in <module>()
    134 
    135             # Compute average losses
--> 136             avg_cost1 += c_1 / total_batch
    137             avg_cost2 += c_2 / total_batch
    138             avg_cost3 += c_3 / total_batch

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c_1 is `NoneType`, therefore it cannot do the calculation. The problem is with this line (can't see the line number):

```
_, c_1 = sess.run([loss_op_1, optimizer_1], feed_dict = {X: batch_x, Y: batch_y})
```

because in order to get the loss value back into c_1, you shouldn't ask for the return value from the optimizer but the loss itself `loss_op_1`. Therefore the line should be:

```
c_1, _ = sess.run([loss_op_1, optimizer_1], feed_dict = {X: batch_x, Y: batch_y})
```

This will be the same for c_2 and c_3 analogously.

This is only to fix the listed `TypeError`, I haven't reviewed your code for any other issues.

Comment: Thanks Peter, it worked. However, the last part of the code wasn't printing the three different losses for the specified number of epochs; and I tried different ways to make it work, but failed. Is there a better way of achieving that? I'm sorry for asking this as it may appear silly. Thank you once again for your great help.

Comment: Looks like `c_1` is a numpy array (even if it has just one element), then you average them into `avg_cost1`, still a numpy array. Then put them into a list `avg_cost`, then try to print the first element of the list, still a numpy array, formatted as float. That won't work, you probably get an invalid format for string, or similar. Try to print without a format string, just use `{}`. If that works, you can print `avg_cost[0][0]` so the _element_ of the array... Also, this line `avg_cost = [avg_cost1, avg_cost1, avg_cost1]` I suppose you meant avg_cost2, etc. not the same thing three times?

Comment: Thanks Peter for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to fixing the actual error you may want to add some error handling to catch these errors and deal with the possibility of `None` values occuring in your code using a `try/except` block..

```
try:
    avg_cost1 += c_1 / total_batch
    avg_cost2 += c_2 / total_batch
    avg_cost3 += c_3 / total_batch
    cost_1.append(avg_cost1)
    cost_2.append(avg_cost2)
    cost_3.append(avg_cost3)
except TypeError:
    print('There is nothing here!!')
    #do something else with the None value...

print('continuing script...')
```

Comment: Thanks Johashu for your input, it really helped. Is there a way I can print the three losses for the specified epochs (say 10 epochs)? The last part of the code wasn't actually printing anything despite several attempts to make it do that.